# A music player that can handle multiple artist tags

Tags: music, rhythmbox, mp3, id3

The mp3 format can handle multiple artists per track (in the form of "artist1\artist2"), and as far as I know other modern music formats can do the same thing. However, Rhythmbox (my default music player) seems to be capable of only reading the first artist. Are there any music players that can read and sort songs with multiple artists, or a plugin for Rhythmbox that can provide this functionality?

Comment: Feature requets: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123446

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will handle multiple values for pretty much any tag where supported by the format (e.g. mp3). It also knows about other person-like tags such as `albumartist`, `performer` and `composer` and has meta-tags for these.

Comment: I actually already had Quod Libet installed but I had never really used it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I was going to write about [puddletag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/puddletag/) ([Things you should know](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/source/tut3.html)), but relalized that I confused Quod Libet with Ex Falso.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for those who use Rhythmbox, and I'm [crossposting](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318579#c43) this from it's issue tracker:

Since I use [Picard](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) for properly tagging albums BEFORE I import them into Rhythmbox (and also, before they're copyed into ~/music), I managed to find a workaround for this.

Picard has a plugin (included out-of-the-box) called "Feat. artists in titles". The name is pretty self-explanatory. Here's an example:

Before:

```
title: "Some song"
artist: "Artist 1 feat. Artist 2"
```

After:

```
title: "Some song feat Artist 2"
artist: "Artist 1"
```

This results in what we all expect in the artist list in Rhythmbox, etc.

I already used picard to complete missing tags (sometimes the year is missing, etc, etc), so it's not really any hastle for me. It may not be the *cleanest* workaround, but it definitely works. I've yet to come any issue with this.