# Play tracks from a FLAC file

Tags: music, music-player, flac

Is there any music player to show tracks of an album when a single FLAC file is played?

`cuetools` can split the album file into song files, but I do not want to change the FLAC single file. I just want to play the entire album when individual tracks are distinguishable.

Comment: Test Clementine. sudo -i // apt-add-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine // apt-get update // apt-get install clementine

Comment: One does not need to add PPA to install Clementine. And it does work, but not in all cases.

Comment: [Foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/), which work well through Wine, can open CUE sheets.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foobar2000-like music player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38970/foobar2000-like-music-player)

Answer (score -1):

I recall playing files/archives with embedded cuesheet information in Amarok 2.x a few years ago, but I gave up on this esoteric approach to archiving as well as archaic and naive attempt to tagging recordings that isn't very popular outside of certain piracy forums.

(Realize that there do not only exist bands and individual artists or projects for eternity who produce songs/recordings with names covered by the latin alphabet of only one particular genre, but that there is a lot more that can and should be covered with metadata if you are still collecting recordings and want to make the most out of your personal collection. Just look at lineup changes and forming of superbands or subgroups to get a glimpse. Just stuffing artists somewhere that won't fit anywhere else due to limited tagging capabilities is the wrong approach. [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/327511/40581), [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/165236/40581), [3](https://community.kde.org/Amarok/Proposals/Support_for_multiple_tags))

**Related:** [Foobar2000-like music player?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38970/40581)